# File upload limit

Tags: php, server, upload, filesize

I got below info from my server as `upload_max_filesize` using `phpinfo();`

[image]

Now my question is "how large file can I upload to my server" ?

Comment: hmmm i think you can upload max file size of 100 MB

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the uploaded file size in php.ini file,
open your php.ini file and search "upload_max_filesize" there increase the uploaded file size

Comment: Thanks @Thiyagu. I am using shared server. Thanks